# Scaffold WhereExpression ignored

Tags: subsonic

I'm using SubSonic with an Sqlite database, everything works very well, but one thing that doesn't is the **WhereExpression** in the Scaffold component.
I haven't been able to get it to work.
  
    WhereExpression="Emember=true"
    TableName="blah"
    >

Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Never had the problem. I always like to bind in a method on a code behind, that way I can control the binding process.

The syntax is similar to below.

```
Dim sublist as new SubSonic.SqlQuery().From("Table").Where("ColumnName").IsEqualTo("Value").ExecuteList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe we fixed this in a recent patch (from you I believe!). Can you do me favor and pull the latest (rev 509 I think) and see if it fixes your issue?